# Hide Second <DT> using Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide the first and second description term and data. (dt & dd). I found a similair question regarding tables and hiding the second . But for some reason the code is not working for me. Any suggestions.

```
<div class="tribe-events-meta-group tribe-events-meta-group-other">
<h3 class="tribe-events-single-section-title"> Other </h3>
<dl>
                <dt> Already An Approved Group? </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            Yes, nothing has changed            </dd>
                <dt> Have You Been Approved for a Room? </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            Yes         </dd>
                <dt> Room Number </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            302         </dd>
                <dt> Will Childcare Be Available </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            Yes         </dd>
                <dt> Restrictions </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            none            </dd>
                <dt> Cost </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            Free            </dd>
                <dt> Registration Required </dt>
        <dd class="tribe-meta-value">
            No          </dd>
        </dl>
```

Here was the code that was used to hide the second table row.

```
 <div class="NewsResultsList">   
    <table border="1" id="table">
        <tr><td>News Results based on user queries</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Random news results</td></tr>
     </table>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function (){
$('div.NewsResultsList table tr:eq(1)').remove()
```

})​

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `:first-of-type` selector to do this:

```
.tribe-events-meta-group dl dt:first-of-type,
.tribe-events-meta-group dl dd:first-of-type { display:none; }
```

In this example I'm hiding the first `dt` and the first `dd` inside the `dl` which is inside a parent element whose class is `tribe-events-meta-group`.

The selector can be changed if you need it to apply to all definition lists on the page etc.

Comment: Thanks HaukurHaf! it worked perfectly, but why does (second-of-type) work?

Comment: nth-of-type(2)  I see!

Comment: Cool :-)  There is no such selector (second-of-type), only first-of-type.

Comment: Exactly, nth-of-type can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dt:first-child,
dt:first-child + dd {
   display: none;
}
```

This will hide first child dt and it's first sibling dd.